# JavaScript OOP - Function call inheritance not working

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, javascript-objects

I have 2 files (`FPDevice.js` and `FPComponent.js`). Each file with an object. I need to call a function from one file (Object) to the other file (Object).

It is working but not as expected using `FPComponent.prototype.onSysexEvent.call(FPComponent);` on file `FPDevice.js` file. I was expecting that by using `FPComponent`, instead of `this` in the context argument, that the function would inherit the properties of the `FPComponent` object and be able to use this.channels.

1. When `FPComponent.prototype.onSysexEvent.call(FPComponent);` function is called from the `FPMidiDevice.prototype.onSysexEvent` function, the call works but the inheritance is not working.
2. I get an error - `this.channels is undefined`
3. Since `this.channels` is a property of the `FPComponent` object, I need the inheritance of call `FPComponent.prototype.onSysexEvent.call(FPComponent)` to be from the `FPComponent` object so I can use the `this.channels` property within the `FPComponent.prototype.onSysexEvent`.

4. The outcome I am looking for is to have Function `FPComponent.prototype.onSysexEvent` inherit the properties from `FPComponent` object once it is called from the `FPMidiDevice.prototype.onSysexEvent` function.

FPDevice.js

```
//FPDevice.js

var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () 
{
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(b, p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();

include_file("resource://com.presonus.musicdevices/sdk/controlsurfacecomponent.js");
include_file("resource://com.presonus.musicdevices/sdk/controlsurfacedevice.js");
include_file("FPComponent.js");

var FPMidiDevice = (function (_super) 
{
    __extends(FPMidiDevice, _super);    
    
    function FPMidiDevice(faderCount, sysexHeader) 
    {       
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this.faderCount = faderCount;
        _this.sysexHeader = sysexHeader;
        _this.lastActiveSensing = 0;
        _this.activeSensingInterval = 2500;             
        return _this;
    }
    
    FPMidiDevice.prototype.onInit = function (hostDevice) 
    {
        _super.prototype.onInit.call(this, hostDevice);
        this.meters = [];              
    };  
    
         FPMidiDevice.prototype.onSysexEvent = function (data, length) 
     {                  
        //##########################################################################################################    //##########################################################################################################
        // I am trying to use call but using FPComponent object so the call can inherit the properties from FPComponent         
        
         FPComponent.prototype.onSysexEvent.call(FPComponent);                       
     };  
    
    
    return FPMidiDevice;
}(PreSonus.ControlSurfaceDevice));

function createFP16DeviceInstance()
 {
    return new FPMidiDevice(16, FP.Support.kSysexHeaderFP16);
}
```

FPComponent.js

```
//FPComponent.js

var __extends = (this && this.__extends) || (function () {
    var extendStatics = function (d, b) {
        extendStatics = Object.setPrototypeOf ||
            ({ __proto__: [] } instanceof Array && function (d, b) { d.__proto__ = b; }) ||
            function (d, b) { for (var p in b) if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(b, p)) d[p] = b[p]; };
        return extendStatics(d, b);
    };
    return function (d, b) {
        extendStatics(d, b);
        function __() { this.constructor = d; }
        d.prototype = b === null ? Object.create(b) : (__.prototype = b.prototype, new __());
    };
})();

include_file("resource://com.presonus.musicdevices/sdk/controlsurfacecomponent.js");
include_file("resource://com.presonus.musicdevices/sdk/controlsurfacedevice.js");

var FPComponent = (function (_super) 
{   
    __extends(FPComponent, _super);

    function FPComponent(faderCount) 
    {
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this.faderCount = faderCount;
        _this.pagingStatusIndex = faderCount - 1;
        _this.channels = [];
        return _this;
    }       

 FPComponent.prototype.onInit = function (hostComponent) 
    {
        
        PreSonus.ControlSurfaceComponent.prototype.onInit.call(this, hostComponent);            
       
        this.model = hostComponent.model;
        this.root = this.model.root;
        this.mixerMapping = this.root.find("MixerMapping");
        this.channelBankElement = this.mixerMapping.find("ChannelBankElement");        
        var paramList = hostComponent.paramList;
                
        for (var i = 0; i < this.faderCount; i++) 
        {
            var channel = new ChannelStrip;                 
            channel.channelElement = this.channelBankElement.getElement(i);                 
            channel.textValue = paramList.addAlias("textValue" + i);
            channel.panValue = paramList.addAlias("panValue" + i);
            channel.muteValue = paramList.addAlias("muteValue" + i);
            channel.soloValue = paramList.addAlias("soloValue" + i);
            channel.recordValue = paramList.addAlias("recordValue" + i);
            channel.monitorValue = paramList.addAlias("monitorValue" + i);
            channel.colorValue = paramList.addAlias("colorValue" + i);            
            
            this.channels.push(channel);                    

        }
    };  
    
    //########################################################################################################
    // it is not working properly when called from FPMidiDevice.prototype.onSysexEvent on file FPMidiDevice.js  
    // error = this.channels is undefined
    
    FPComponent.prototype.onSysexEvent = function () 
     {          
        var  channelIndex = 0;  
        var channel =  this.channels[channelIndex];
        channel.faderValue.value = 1;       
        
      };          
      
          return FPComponent;
           
}(PreSonus.ControlSurfaceComponent));
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not getting something here, but `channels` is an instance variable. It does not exist on the `FPComponent` constructor itself, which you are passing as the `this` context (`FPComponent.onSysexEvent()` won't work). I think you must first instantiate an FPComponent object somewhere `var obj = new FPComponent();`. Then you can just call `obj.onSysexEvent()`.

Comment: Is this transpiled code? If yes, please post the original source code, if no, why are you using such weird functions like `__extends`?